# How to change the language of 'Google News' regarding the GSnewsBar object (Ajax API)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, localization

The following deals with GSnewsBar object of the Goolge-Ajax search API which is explained here:

http://www.google.com/uds/solutions/newsbar/reference.html

There are some parameters which allow to change the layout of the news. But there is no example of how to set the news language.

Currently I always get news in English but my aim is to provide the user a selectbox which provides different languages (en,de,it,nl,es,...). Which object/method should be used to change the language before requesting news?

Comment: I don't know the first thing about GSnewsBar, but when working with embedded Google Maps you can change the display language by attaching `&hl=en` to the URL of the script. Maybe it works here too?

Comment: That works fine. But what about changing the language dynamically for example by a selectbox. Is there is an alternative to do this without reloading the script?

Comment: Did you try to use the Accept-Language http header?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below option

```
var loadOptions = {packages : ["newsshow"]};
loadOptions.language = "en";
google.load("elements", "1", loadOptions);
```

For more information please visit the below link. It provides a detailed description about your issue

[Google News API](https://developers.google.com/news-search/newsshow/)